# Theano implementation of Stacked DenoisingAutoencoders - Why same input to dA layers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, autoencoder

In the tutorial Stacked DenoisingAutoencoders on http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/SdA.html#sda, the pretraining_functions return a list of functions which represent the train function of each dA layer. But I don't understand why it gives all the dA layers the same input (`train_set_x`). Actually, the input of each dA layer should be the output of the layer below except the first dA layer. Can anybody tell me why these codes are correct?

```
pretrain_fns = []
for dA in self.dA_layers:
    # get the cost and the updates list
    cost, updates = dA.get_cost_updates(corruption_level, learning_rate)
    # compile the theano function
    fn = theano.function(inputs=[index,
                      theano.Param(corruption_level, default=0.2),
                      theano.Param(learning_rate, default=0.1)],
            outputs=cost,
            updates=updates,
            givens={self.x: train_set_x[batch_begin:batch_end]})
    # append `fn` to the list of functions
    pretrain_fns.append(fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the inputs of each hidden layer are configured as the outputs of the previous layer:

```
# the input to this layer is either the activation of the hidden
# layer below or the input of the SdA if you are on the first
# layer
if i == 0:
    layer_input = self.x
else:
    layer_input = self.sigmoid_layers[-1].output
```

When setting `self.x` to `train_set_x[batch_begin:batch_end]` in `givens` section of the pretraining function it actually makes theano propagate the inputs from one layer to the other, so when you pre-train the second layer the inputs will first propagate through the first layer and then be processed by the second.

If you look closely at the end of the [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/SdA.html#tips-and-tricks) there is a tip how to reduce the training run-time by precomputing the explicit inputs per layer.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite understand why theano can propagate the inputs into next layer. Because we only provide a certain parameter to the function. The definition of each layer is right, but train_set_x just didn't change during the cycle.

Comment: @love_carrot try print the graph and see how it flows, you'll see the inputs of one layer processed for the second one.